# Use Xilinx Primitive elements in Verilog inside ISE

Tags: verilog, xilinx, ise

I generated Verilog Post-Route simulation model of my original Verilog module, using Xilinx ISE. 
It will generate a Verilog module using LUT and fpga level primitives such as IBUF,X_LUT4, ... 
 When trying to compile this code directly and synthesis it inside ISE itself, it cannot find Xilinx primtivies and assert compilation error such as `ERROR:HDLCompilers:87 - "test.v" line 26 Could not find module/primitive 'X_OPAD'`.
 I want to know how can I include related modules/libraries inside ISE verilog code to avoid compilation errors.

Part of code is brought below:

```
module tripler (
  TRIPLED_OUTPUT, INPUT_SIGNAL
);
  output TRIPLED_OUTPUT;
  input INPUT_SIGNAL;
  wire INPUT_SIGNAL_IBUF_23;
  wire GATE3_OUT_0;
  wire GATE1_OUT_0;
  wire GATE2_OUT_0;
  wire GATE4_OUT_0;
  wire GATE5_OUT_0;
  wire GATE6_OUT_0;
  wire \TRIPLED_OUTPUT/O ;
  wire \INPUT_SIGNAL/INBUF ;
  wire GATE3_OUT;
  wire GATE1_OUT;
  wire GATE2_OUT;
  wire GATE4_OUT;
  wire GATE5_OUT;
  wire GATE6_OUT;
  wire TRIPLE_OUT;
  wire VCC;

  X_OPAD #(
    .LOC ( "PAD1" ))
  \TRIPLED_OUTPUT/PAD  (
    .PAD(TRIPLED_OUTPUT)
  );
  X_OBUF #(
    .LOC ( "PAD1" ))
  TRIPLED_OUTPUT_OBUF (
    .I(\TRIPLED_OUTPUT/O ),
    .O(TRIPLED_OUTPUT)
  );
  X_IPAD #(
    .LOC ( "PAD2" ))
  \INPUT_SIGNAL/PAD  (
    .PAD(INPUT_SIGNAL)
  );
  INPUT_SIGNAL_IBUF (
    .I(INPUT_SIGNAL),
    .O(\INPUT_SIGNAL/INBUF )
  );
  X_BUF #(
    .LOC ( "PAD2" ))
  \INPUT_SIGNAL/IFF/IMUX  (
    .I(\INPUT_SIGNAL/INBUF ),
    .O(INPUT_SIGNAL_IBUF_23)
  );
  X_BUF #(
    .LOC ( "SLICE_X0Y13" ))
  \GATE3_OUT/XUSED  (
    .I(GATE3_OUT),
    .O(GATE3_OUT_0)
  );
  X_BUF #(
    .LOC ( "SLICE_X0Y13" ))
  \GATE3_OUT/YUSED  (
    .I(GATE1_OUT),
    .O(GATE1_OUT_0)
  );
```

Comment: Why are you trying to synthesize a simulation model? X_ modules are from the Xilinx simulation library, they are not device primitives.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using X_ macros directly? Are you looking to do something that can't be done with the 'normal' primitive set (IBUF/OBUF/etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

Primitives with prefix "X_" don't look like normal primitives.

I tried once to hide pins from top-level. So I instantiated IPAD and OPAD primitives in VHDL by hand.

Results:

- Synthesis XST -> complained about black-boxes
- Translate     -> complained about black-boxes
- Map           -> was very happy
- P&R           -> run as normal
- BitGen        -> run as normal
- test on FPGA  -> all as expected

Xilinx has several primitive libraries:

- UNISIM
- UNIMACRO
- UNIPRIM
- ...

I don't know if there is also a documentation for XST/iSim, but I found this for Synth/xSim (Vivado): [Vivado Design Suite User Guide - Logic Simulation (UG900)](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_4/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf). Have a look at pages 14 ff. It lists all libraries and when they are bound in simulation (post synth. / post impl.)

Comment: I did include SIMPRIM modules (modules to simulate post place & route delays) to my design which include those X_BUF and ... modules. However Xilinx is now compalining about missing item which is `glbl` module. I added it as well but it seems that ISE ignore it. `glbl` module is a module which is intended to drive reset pins of all elements inside FPGA. However I don't know what is missing. Currently I added Name glbl module to my code however here is Xilinx compiler complaint: `'glbl.GTS' could not be resolved` !

Comment: There is a `-insert_glbl` switch in the Simulation Process Properties. Parameter description: *Automatically Insert glbl Module in the Netlist* - I never change such things, maybe it helps.